# How to Center Child with Absolute Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div's inside another div, and I want to center child div.So,Please How can I do this?

```
#father {
   position: relative;
}

#son1 {
   position: absolute;
   width:285px;
}

#son2 {
   position: absolute;
   width:285px;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML markup too please?

Comment: center horizontally? vertically? both?

Comment: `top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;` - Put this on the absolute positioned elements and it will center.

Comment: @Ruddy this centers only horizontally untill the OP add some height for his div though he has the width mentioned already. No hard feelings

Comment: @Benjamin Correct, the OP didn't state what they wanted so covered it all.

Comment: Yes you covered it all but don't try to mislead, you need to more clear what you say. Just wanna make you correct.

Comment: 1) Centering horizontally or vertically is something else entirely.  You should specify this in the question 2) There are gazillions of questions like this, you should do a search before you ask..

Comment: @Benjamin If the OP gives a question that isn't very well asked then I will give a answer (in the form of a comment) that is on the same level.

Comment: @Ruddy yep I agree that.

Comment: need Centering horizontally

Comment: can't set it left and right because i am using isotop which will put left and right dynamically

Answer (score 5):

First, you set a 50% left to the child element. Now the left side of the child element is at the middle of it's parent element. So, in order to bring the child's element center at it's parent center, set a negative left margin of it's half width (285 / 2 = 142.5).
Sorry for my english!

```
#son1, #son2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -142.5px;
}
```

**EDIT**

In order to center the child elements inside their parent element, and have the child elements next to each other check this:

```css
#father {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#child-wrapper {
    width: 580px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -290px;
}

#child-wrapper > div:first-child {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#child-wrapper > div {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

#son1, #son2 {
    width: 285px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="father">
    <div id="child-wrapper">
        <div id="son1">Son1</div>
        <div id="son2">Son2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are assuming that the two 'sons' are to be on top of each other. What about if they are supposed be next to each other...as seems likely.

Answer (score 2):

```
#son1, #son2 
{
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can you have to set top and left with margin-top and margin-left

You can check code here

```css
#father {
      position: relative;
      background: green;
      height:150px;
      width:300px;
   
   }
   
   #son1 {
      position: absolute;
      width:100px;
      margin-left:-50px; /* -half of width */
      height:50px;
      background: yellow;
      left:50%;
      top:50%;
      margin-top:-25px; /* -half of height*/
     
   }
   #son2 {
      position: absolute;
      width:50px;
      margin-left:-25px; /* -half of width */
      height:30px;
      background: red;
      left:50%;
      top:50%;
      margin-top:-15px; /* -half of height*/
     
   }
```

```html
<div id="father">
  <div id="son1"></div>
  <div id="son2"></div>
  
 </div>
```